# 2 forms using PHP. One for adding and one for adding changes

Tags: php, mysql

I'm still making the orderform, I've been working on the "save changes function". 
By this I mean, if people make changes to the table, they can click on a button and it will update the database (where I get my data from).

[Link to the image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp1F5.jpg)

"Bestelling toevoegen" is the adding form, if I fill in the form, and click on "Toevoegen" it will display a new record to the table above.

The problem is, I can't seem to save the changes (Wijzigigen opslaan) of "Status".

Here's the full code:

```
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bestelformulier");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM overzicht");
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo "<table align='center' width='700px' border='2'>
    <tr>
    <th>Ordernr</th>
    <th>Klantnaam</th>
    <th>Productnaam</th>
    <th>ProductID</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    </tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {

    $status = $row['status'];
    $ordernr = $row['ordernr'];

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['ordernr'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='150px'>" . $row['klantnaam'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td width='200px'>" . $row['productnaam'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['productid'] . "</td>";

    echo "<td><select>
      <option>" . $row['status'] . "</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Niet besteld")
      echo "<option>Niet besteld</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Besteld")
      echo "<option>Besteld</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie")
      echo "<option>Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Onderweg naar vestiging")
      echo "<option>Onderweg naar vestiging</option>";
      if($row['status']  != "Ontvangen")
      echo "<option>Ontvangen</option>";
    echo "</select></td>";

    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td>";
    echo "<td><input type='submit' name='wijzigen' value='Wijzigingen Opslaan'/></td>";
    echo "</tr>";

    echo "</table>";
    echo "</form>";

    if(isset($_POST['wijzigen'])) {

    $query = mysqli_query("UPDATE overzicht SET status=$status WHERE ordernr=$ordernr");
    }

    mysqli_close($con);

    //Table Toevoegen
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","bestelformulier");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    echo "<br/><br/><br/>";
    echo "<h5>Bestelling Toevoegen</h5>";
    echo "<form method='post'>";
    echo "<table width='700px' border='1'>

    <tr>
      <th>klantnaam</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='klantnaam'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>Productnaam</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='productnaam'/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <th>productid</th>
        <td><input type='text' name='productid'/></td>
    </tr>



    <tr>
       <th>Status</th>
       <td>
         <select name='status'>
           <option value='Niet besteld'>Niet besteld</option>
           <option value='Besteld'>Besteld</option>
           <option value='Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie'>Onderweg naar hoofdlocatie</option>
           <option value='Onderweg naar vestiging'>Onderweg naar vestiging</option>
           <option value='Ontvangen'>Ontvangen</option>
         <select>
       </td>

    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><input type='submit' name='toevoegen' value='Toevoegen'/></td>
    </tr>";


    echo "</table>";


    $klantnaam = $_POST['klantnaam'];
    $productnaam = $_POST['productnaam'];
    $productid = $_POST['productid'];
    $status= $_POST['status'];

    if(isset($_POST['toevoegen'])) {

    $query = mysqli_query($con,"INSERT INTO overzicht (klantnaam, productnaam, productid, status)
    VALUES ('$klantnaam', '$productnaam', '$productid', '$status')");

    $current_url = (empty($_SERVER['HTTPS']) ? "http://" : "https://") . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    header ('Location: ' . $current_url);
    exit ();
    }
    echo "</form>";
    mysqli_close($con);
```

Hope I made it all clear for you, if not I will reply as soon as possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not reading the status from the `$_POST` variable.

You are reading `$status` from the database:

```
$status = $row['status'];
```

and then you are setting it again

```
$query = mysqli_query("UPDATE overzicht SET status=$status WHERE ordernr=$ordernr");
```

So you set it to the same value as it already is.

Add a `$status = $_POST['status'];` before the query. Also, you are not reading `$ordernr` from `$_POST`, so you are always setting the status to the last item read from your database.

You are also missing single quotes in the query, it should be `status='$status'`. Last, but not least, take a look at prepared statements. Right now your code is vulnarable to SQL injections.

**Edit:**
You have to rethink the form of your list. Your `select` elements don't have a name, so it can't be transmitted to the server at all. Also, you have to provide the ID of the order number for each order ... either you make a form for each order (I'd recommend that), or you use arrays for your form element names (for example: `<select name="status[$ordernr]">`, simplified).

Comment: So I delete the database one, and place the POST one in the isset before $query? it still doesn't work after that.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by that

Comment: well, I'm having $status = $_POST['status']; in isset(wijzigen)

I've also added the single quotes to the SET and WHERE.

tried $ordernr on POST, but didn't work.
do you maybe know what I did wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Why in the universe you have assigned `$status = $row['status'];` and not using `$status` in your while Loop.
Second you are using single quotes around variables in the insert query, you don't have to do this, else mysqli will take them as string instead of variables, put the variables in double quotes and query in single.
If this doesn't help, try printing the post data. Also you haven't given name to your forms. Please give forms some name and to your form elements as well. 
This may help.

Comment: wow, that made a lot of sense. I would like to thank you for your helping critisism. I will sort out these matters. Thanks a lot!

Comment: actually this is just wrong. Your insert query is just fine, the quotes are exactly right.